# How to use Provider Package for Map<String, ModelClass>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when i use 'Late' with Map<String, CartModel> _items;
the lateinitialization error removes.
but if the list is empty then the lateinitialization error appear.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:shop1/model/cart_item.dart';

    class ShopProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    late Map<String, CartItem> _items;

    ShopProvider() {

    _items = {
      '1': CartItem(
          id: '1',
          title: 'sikki',
          imgUrl: 'assets/cocacola.png',
          qnt: 2,
          price: 13)
    };

  }

  Map<String, CartItem> get items => _items;
  set items(Map<String, CartItem> value) {
    _items = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of late initialization, you can initialize it in its declaration:

```dart
class ShopProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = [];

  // omitted
}
```

You can also initialize it in the constructor, either via a passed argument, or via initializer list:

```dart
class ShopProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items;

  // Passing an argument
  ShopProvider(this._items);

  // OR passing a named argument
  ShopProvider({ 
    required Map<String, CartItem> items,
  }): _items = items;

  // OR using initializer list only
  ShopProvider(): _items = [];

  // rest of class omitted
}
```

---

For a bit more context, all of the members of a class are supposed to already be initialized when the body of a constructor runs. So:

```dart
ShopProvider() {
  // All members must be initialized BEFORe code in this block runs,
  // or otherwise be marked as "late" - but you must be sure
  // to initialize any "late" variables before they are used.
}
```

That's why we use initializer lists - Those initializations occur *before* the constructor body, as do initializations in the declarations of member fields.

Finally, the syntax:

```
ShopProvider(this._items);
```

is really just a shorthand for doing this:

```
ShopProvider(Map<String, CartItem> items): _items = items;
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Horn, The third option to "use initializer list only" solved my problem.